# Pickup vs. Pick Up vs. Pick-up

Tags: terminology

Researching another question, [Takeout vs Pickup, is there a difference?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/167845/takeout-vs-pickup-is-there-a-differnce) - and at first I used "pick-up" - but it appears that pickup would be a better choice.

Is this correct, and how do you fit one of the three terms to its usage?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've always used hyphenation for the compound modifier. Pick up for the verb and pickup for the truck or any other time that it is used as a noun.

So I would say "Drive your pickup to pick up the kids at the pick-up location."

However the distinction between adjective and noun seems to be going away over time. The OED traces "pickup truck" as starting out as "pick-up truck" in the 1920s and morphing in to "pickup truck" later on and google ngrams would agree with that assessment:
[image]

The OED at least is fairly adamant still that "pick up" as two words can only be used as a phrasal verb.